# What is start_daemon?

Tags: startup, command-line, services, init.d

I'm trying to understand `start_daemon` in the following `/etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server` startup script:

```
  start)
        if [ "$INETD" = 1 ]; then
                exit 1
        fi
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
        start_daemon -p $PIDDIR/nrpe.pid $NICENESS $DAEMON  -c $CONFIG -d $DAEMON_OPTS
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
```

In particular, when I start this service it isn't writing a PID file as expected, thus the `stop service nagios-nrpe-server` command is not working (I need to manually kill the processes).

I'm trying to figure out how to trouble shoot the problem, but I can't run `start_daemon ...` from the command line.

I want to reproduce what the script is doing manually so I can work on what the problem is.

Comment: The ultimate solution to this problem, in case someone finds this post and is experiencing the same issue with the NRPE daemon, was to fix the PID setting in /etc/nrpe.cfg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a shell function in `/lib/lsb/init-functions`. You should see `. /lib/lsb/init-functions` earlier in the init script.

Comment: Aha! Sneaky buggers. I see where it's coming from now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like as it was function call in the shell script.

Check the bash manual (`man bash`) and search for *„shell function definition”* (`/` command).